# Convert program in Java to Assembler?

Tags: java, assembly

I have to do a program to school in Assembler but we did just a few basic things. Is it possible to write code in Java and convert it to Assembler?

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: I'm pretty certain the goal of your class is to teach *you* to write assembly code, not the computer.

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/285888/how-do-java-aot-compilers-work and http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do Java AOT compilers work?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/285888/how-do-java-aot-compilers-work)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Converting a program from one language to another is always possible as long as the target language is computationally powerful enough to express the semantics of the program. In particular, it is always possible if the target language is Turing-complete. Converting a program from one language to another is called "compilation" and it can be done by a program, such a program is called a "compiler". So, you just need to find (or write) a compiler from Java to assembler.

Comment: Java contains a lot of classes in the JDK that have nothing to do with your program. Are you going to submit the assembly code for them too? And if you are not, how do you make your calls to methods in the JDK do something, since there is no direct counterpart in assembly?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. While normally Java is compiled to bytecode executed by JVM, there are compilers that output native code. For example, `gcc` has Java front-end, the `gcj`, so you can use that along with `-s` option (which emits assembly output instead of machine code).

Having said that, don't expect to fool anyone. Your teacher will instantly recognise that your code has not been written by you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I know it probably wouldn't look exactly the same but my teacher really don't care. He didn't teach us anything except add and sub and he doesn't even know a lot of stuff when you ask him. He just want to see that our program works.

Comment: I mean, unless your teacher totally don't care, it will be instantly recognizable as machine-generated code.